# Playwright: localStorage set up does not work

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, playwright-test

The application includes a tooltip that should be displayed when the localStorage is set to false, and I expect it to be hidden or non-existent in the DOM when localStorage is true. I've attempted various scenarios to achieve this, but all of my examples have been unsuccessful, as demonstrated below. How can I accomplish my intended outcome?

I did come across a solution in the documentation that utilizes `global.setup`, but I'd prefer not to use it. My preference is to implement this solution solely within my current test file.

I'm using `next.js`, and I'm unsure if there are any specific limitations related to it.

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page, context }) => {
  await context.addCookies([
    { name: 'ab_tests_value', value: 'test128=variantA', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' },
  ]);

  // It does not allow to use localStorage before page is loaded
  await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.setItem('xxx', val), 'true'));

  await page.goto(`localhost:3000/en/search`);
});
  
test('should appear if already seen', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page.getByText('tooltip content')).not.toBeAttached();
});
```

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page, context }) => {
  await context.addCookies([
    { name: 'ab_tests_value', value: 'test128=variantA', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' },
  ]);

  // ./storage.json is as below
  // { "origins": [ { "localStorage": [ { "name": "tooltip": "true" } ] } ]} 
  await context.storageState({ path: './storage.json' });

  await page.goto(`localhost:3000/en/search`);
});
  
test('should not appear if already seen', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page.getByText('tooltip content')).not.toBeAttached();
});
```

```
test.beforeEach(async ({ page, context }) => {
  await context.addCookies([
    { name: 'ab_tests_value', value: 'test128=variantA', path: '/', domain: 'localhost' },
  ]);
  await page.goto(`localhost:3000/en/search`);

  await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.setItem('xxx', val), 'true'));
  // I could not see value in localStorage
});
  
test('should not appear if already seen', async ({ page }) => {
  await expect(page.getByText('tooltip content')).not.toBeAttached();
});
```

Want to be mocked localStorage value